# String Extraction

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut, tr

I have a file with the text pattern:

```
AAAA - BBBB (CCCC) - (DDDD)
```

I'm only interested in using the first set AAAA - BBBB individually (i.e. AAAA and BBBB) I've chopped off the '(CCCC) - (DDDD)' using:

```
FIRST_SET="${STRING%% (*}"
```

giving me 'AAAA - BBBB'.

For the life of me I can't extract 'AAAA' from the second 'BBBB'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you change your sample to have different data instead of `XXXX` repeated four times? I'm finding it difficult to understand which one you want to extract/

Comment: AAAA - BBBB (CCCC) - (DDDD)

Comment: To give a better idea of what you want, add the expected output to your question. Without that, it's difficult to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is the string in a file or in a variable? Do we need to parse a file or a shell variable?

Comment: Yes it's a variable pulled from a file.

Comment: This page (https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) explains sed very well -
also it has a fantastic set of other unix tutorials
(https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/index.html). Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it like your first step:

```
FIRST_SET="${STRING%% (*}"
FIRST_WORD=${FIRST_SET%% *}
SECOND_WORD=${FIRST_SET##* }
```

Comment: Thanks all. I never rely understood how to do it but it helps a ton.

Comment: THNX, I still have issues because the service creating the file keeps changing the format on me. Now I have a better understanding og sed though.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want the final result in two shell variables, that the words that you want are delimited by whitespace, that there is no whitespace embedded in the words, and that the `IFS` variable has the default value:

```
$ read -r word1 dash word2 junk <file
$ printf 'word1 = "%s"\nword2 = "%s"\n' "$word1" "$word2"
word1 = "AAAA"
word2 = "BBBB"
```

The `read` command used here will read in the first word into the variable `word1` and it will read the second word into the variable `word2`.  The dash between the words is read into the variable `dash` and the junk at the end get placed in the variable called `junk`.

Comment: I used read to pull in the info but never really used read to it;s full potential.. THNX!

Comment: Thnx, it really helps me understand how I can use string extraction.